# Return HTML Form in Express App/NodeJS

Tags: jquery, node.js, express

I'm building a basic user interface where a user can input a word and a score and this is being written to a local JSON file. This is for a sentiment analysis api. I have everything running fine in Express and when I enter a route it successfully enters the word and the score into my JSON file.

The problem is that my inputs in the HTML don't work. Every-time I enter a word and a score I get a 404 in my console. When I click on the url that I generate and put it in the browser it successfully submits the data to the JSON. So I'm wondering what is wrong with my inputs and my jQuery post request?

Code:

```js
$.getJSON("/all", function(data)  {
  var keys = Object.keys(data);
  console.log(keys);

  $("#submit").click(function() {
    var word = $('#word').val();
    var score = $('#score').val();
    console.log(word, score);
    var url1 = "add/";
    var url = url1 + word + '/' +  score;


      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        success: function(data) {
          console.log('succes');
          console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
        }
      })

});

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>New Website</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="data:image/x-icon;," type="image/x-icon">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <p>
    Word: <input id="word" type="text" name="word" value="" placeholder="word">
    <br/>
    Score: <input id="score" type="number" name="score" value="" placeholder="score">
    <br/>
    <button id="submit" type="button" name="button">Submit</button>
    </p>





    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

```js
var fs = require('fs');
var data = fs.readFileSync('words.json');
var words = JSON.parse(data);

console.log('server is starting');

console.log(words);


var express = require('express');

var app = express();


var server = app.listen(3000, listening);

function listening(){
  console.log('listening...')
}

  app.use(express.static('Website'));



    app.get('/add/:word/:score', addWord);

    function addWord(request, response){
        var data = request.params;
        var word = data.word;
        var score = Number(data.score);

        words[word] = score;
        var data = JSON.stringify(words,null,2);
        fs.writeFile('words.json', data, finished);

        function finished(err) {
          console.log('all set.');


        var reply = {
          status: "Success",
          word: word,
          score: score
        }
        response.send(reply);
    }
    }


    app.get('/all', sendAll);

    function sendAll(request,response){
      response.send(words);
    }
```

Comment: Post your node.js code.

Comment: It's there now @JesseSchokker

Comment: Why are you writing it to a JSON file? Why not use a database?

Comment: I'd like to. But I first want to figure out how to write to a local file first. Then I'll probably look at MongoDB or something else to write to

Answer (score 0):

Solved by changing the Ajax request to 'GET' rather than 'POST'.